# Data is not sending to player in MultiPlayer MatchMatching game

Tags: swift, game-center, ios8.1

I am working on a Multiplayer game Tic-Tac-Toe. Where first player sending their tapped position to another player by it's tag. In my case , first player sending tapped position successfully but when second player send it position, NSData showing nil. Why this happening.

Sending data coding is here:

```
 func fieldTapped(recornizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    var tagNumber = recornizer.view?.tag
    let data = NSData(bytes: &tagNumber, length: sizeof(Int))
    var error: NSError?
            if (multiplayerMatch?.sendDataToAllPlayers(data, withDataMode: .Unreliable, error: &error) != nil) {
                println("error sending data: \(error)")
            }

}
```

DataReceived is here:

```
   func match(match: GKMatch!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromPlayer playerID: String!) {
    if multiplayerMatch != match {
        return
    }

    print(playerID)
    //delegate?.matchReceivedData(match, data: data, fromPlayer: playerID)
    var score: Int = 0
    data.getBytes(&score, length: sizeof(Int))
    print(score)
}
```

What I am missing ? Please get me out from here.